# Segmentation fault after QLabel.setPixmap with PyQt5

Tags: segmentation-fault, pyqt5, python-imaging-library, qpixmap

I'm trying to show a PIL image using QPixmap and QLabel. But when I run the code, I get SIGSEGV.
Code:

```
import sys

from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # im = Image.new('RGB', (200, 200), (255, 255, 255))
        im = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255))
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt(im)))

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(767, 557)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I change image size to 200x200, it doesn't throw segmentation fault but has randomly colorized pixels.

How do I put my PIL image into a window correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `RGBA` format:

```
import sys

from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#        im = Image.new('RGB', (200, 200), (255, 255, 155))
#        im = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255))

        im = Image.new("RGBA", (500, 500), (255, 155, 155, 255))           # <---

        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt(im)))

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(767, 557)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]