# Display image in PyQt5 from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt5

I have an numpy array with shape `(500, 500, 3)`. And I want it to convert into image and show it using PyQt5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the array is of type uint8 and represents the red, green, and blue
You could use `Pillow` for this, e.g.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

from PIL import Image, ImageQt
import numpy as np

# generate data
table = np.zeros((256,256,3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(256):
    table[:,i,0] = i
    table[i,:,1] = i
table[:,:,2] = (2*255 - table[:,:,0] - table[:,:,1]) // 2

# convert data to QImage using PIL
img = Image.fromarray(table, mode='RGB')
qt_img = ImageQt.ImageQt(img)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = QtWidgets.QLabel()
w.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qt_img))
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: This code is working well but some size of numpy array create error called **Segmentation fault**. Try this line `table = np.zeros((257,257,3), dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: Well I've solved this issue also by adding alpha channel to image. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878822/segmentation-fault-after-qlabel-setpixmap-with-pyqt5)